# How to do LDAP authentication in flask restful

Tags: python, authentication, flask, ldap, flask-restful

I need to create LDAP Authentication for a Rest API used within the network of an organization.

I thought I might be able to do this, creating an `AuthUtility` class :

```
class AuthUtility:
    def __init__(self, user_model, user_data):
        self.username = user_model.username
        self.password = user_model.password
        self.parsed_username = user_data.username
        self.parsed_password = user_data.password
        self.parsed_auth_method = user_data.auth_method

    def _is_ldap_authenticated(self) -> bool:
        # TODO: To be replaced by ldap authentication
        return False # Hard-Coded

    def _is_db_authenticated(self) -> bool:
        return self.password == self.parsed_password

    def is_authenticated(self) -> bool:
        auth_method = self.parsed_auth_method
        if auth_method == "ldap":
            return self._is_ldap_authenticated()
        elif auth_method == "db":
            return self._is_db_authenticated()
        else:
            # This should never happen
            print(f"Method {auth_method} not defined!")
            # TODO: Return error! This should never happen!
            return False


class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def find_all(cls) -> List["UserModel"]:
        return cls.query.all()

    @classmethod
    def find_by_username(cls, username: str) -> "UserModel":
        return cls.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    @classmethod
    def find_by_id(cls, _id: int) -> "UserModel":
        return cls.query.filter_by(id=_id).first()

    def save_to_db(self) -> None:
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    def delete_from_db(self) -> None:
        db.session.delete(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

And in my post request to the login endpoint, include a key `auth_method` whose value can be either `ldap` or `db`

```
BODY:
{
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mypassword", 
    "auth_method": "db"
}
```

or

```
BODY:
{
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mypassword", 
    "auth_method": "ldap"
}
```

```
class UserLogin(Resource):
    @classmethod
    def post(cls):
        request_json = request.get_json()
        # Pop auth_method from request_json
        try:
            auth_method = request_json.pop("auth_method")
        except KeyError:
            return {"message": "Authentication method should be defined"}

        user_data = user_schema.load(request_json)
        # Find user in the database
        user = UserModel.find_by_username(user_data.username)
        # Add back auth_method
        user_data.auth_method = auth_method

        # Check if the user with username exist in the database
        if not user:
            return {"message": "user_user_not_found"}, 401
        # Check to see the user is authenticated
        elif not AuthUtility(user, user_data).is_authenticated():
            return {"message": "user_invalid_credentials"}, 401

        # Create and return access_token and refresh_token
        access_token = create_access_token(user.id, fresh=True)
        refresh_token = create_refresh_token(user.id)
        return {"access_token": access_token, "refresh_token": refresh_token}, 200
```

The user can log in through either `db` or `ldap` `auth_method`s.

`db` is clear to me but I do not know how to do it with `ldap`.

Any idea how to actually complete it and actually using it in production?

I also have found some python ldap3 library but really not sure how to use it

I need to write this part:

```
def _is_ldap_authenticated(self) -> bool:
    # TODO: To be replaced by ldap authentication
    return False # Hard-Coded
```

But the question is, how and is there any resource available I can use and see how to do it?

To add some detail about `ldap`, please note that I have done this test and it connects:

```
from ldap3 import SAFE_SYNC, Server, Connection, ALL

ldsp_server = "ldap://***.***.com"
root_dn = "dc=***,dc=com"
ldap_user_name = "***"
ldap_password = "***"


def ldap_test():

    server = Server(ldsp_server, get_info=ALL)
    conn = Connection(
        server,
        user=ldap_user_name,
        password=ldap_password,
        client_strategy=SAFE_SYNC,
        auto_bind=True,
    )
```